# Chrome JS API - Handling Errors Inside Method Callbacks

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I normally use `window.addEventListener("error", function (){ ... });` to listen for unhandled exceptions in my JavaScript. However, errors that happen *inside* callbacks passed to [Chrome JavaScript API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) methods don't seem to bubble-up to the window.

Example:

```
window.addEventListener("error", function (){
    console.warn("error!"); // never triggers
});

chrome.tabs.create({ ... }, function (){
    window.foo(); // exception here (function not defined)
});
```

I can, of course, put a `try...catch` block inside the callback function - but I don't want to have to do that all over the place if I don't have to...

Is there a way to globally listen for (and handle) errors that happen from within these callbacks? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to create a wrapper for the chrome functions that fires the error event.

Comment: Are you asking about errors that occur *in the callback*, or an error that occurred in the API call?

Comment: @DanielHerr Do you mean a wrapper that does the `try...catch...log` for me once, so I don't have to repeat myself everywhere? That's a good idea, and may be the only way - was just wondering if, maybe, the API allowed for, like, a global error event listener or something....

Comment: @Makyen Yes, errors that occur _in the callback_ itself, not API failures.